# How to display the selected menu item in the toggle button of the bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have designed a collapsible menu to be hidden on resizing the browser and the same has to be displayed on toggling the button.

In the toggle button, I have used glyphicon-humberger. Instead, I want to display the selected menu in the toggle button.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button id="button" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>                  
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="sample.png"></a> 
        <div>
            <h4>DIRECTORY</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">DIRECTORY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I have selected the "Directory" page, the toggle button should display Directory as its value.

Comment: Share your css and javascript code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automation provided to do this. You need to use jquery/javascript to do this. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151348/bootstrap-drop-down-set-selected-value) for reference. You may need to use the proper selector to replace `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>` with the selected menu text.

Answer (score 0):

On jsfiddle-> https://jsfiddle.net/Mahua/8bzbv2es

Here is a solution for this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
</button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dashboard" aria-expanded="true">DASHBOARD</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#directory" aria-expanded="false">DIRECTORY</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" aria-expanded="false">CONTACT</a></li>
<li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#about" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content">
<!--dashboard starts-->
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="dashboard">   
<p><b>DASHBOARD</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<!--dashboard ends-->
<!--directory starts-->
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="directory">   
<p><b>DIRECTORY</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<!--directory ends-->
<!--contact starts-->
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">   
<p><b>CONTACT</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<!--contact ends-->
<!--about starts-->
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="about">   
<p><b>ABOUT</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<!--about ends-->
</div>
```

Hope that helps!!